# Presence of polyglossia and setotherlanguage in preamble changes chapter heading format

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, titlesec, polyglossia

When I compile MWE #1, I get Chapter Heading format #1, which is what I want it to look like.

**MWE #1 (XeLaTeX):**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7.5in,
    paperheight=9.25in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]
    {geometry} 

%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles]{titlesec}

        %changes page numbering to bottom outer
        \newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}                   {\thepage}}
        \pagestyle{mystyle}
        %

    %creates the chapter heading style  
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries\rmfamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule
    \vspace{0pc}%
    \footnotesize}
    %
        %changes chapter heading distance from top
        \makeatletter
        \beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.ex\@minus.2ex
        \makeatother
        \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*-2.25}{*2}
        %

    %changes "Chapter" to "Story"   
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{Story}
    \makeatother
    %
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\lipsum[1-24]

\end{document}
```

**Chapter Heading format #1:**
[image]

But when I compile MWE #2, which adds `expex` and `polyglossia` commands to the preamble, then I get Chapter Heading format #2.

**MWE #2 (XeLaTeX):**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7.5in,
    paperheight=9.25in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]
    {geometry} 

%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles]{titlesec}

        %changes page numbering to bottom outer
        \newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}                   {\thepage}}
        \pagestyle{mystyle}
        %

    %creates the chapter heading style  
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries\rmfamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule
    \vspace{0pc}%
    \footnotesize}
    %
        %changes chapter heading distance from top
        \makeatletter
        \beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.ex\@minus.2ex
        \makeatother
        \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*-2.25}{*2}
        %

    %changes "Chapter" to "Story"   
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{Story}
    \makeatother
    %
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\lipsum[1-24]

\end{document}
```

**Chapter Heading format #2:**
[image]

The only difference between the two MWEs is the six lines before `\begin{document}`.

```
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}
```

As far as I can tell, the `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` command is causing a problem. What is happening; why would `polyglossia` or `\setotherlanguage` affect chapter heading formats? And how can I fix it so that I get Chapter Heading format #1 while still using the `expex` and `polyglossia` packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hebrew loads bidi, and bidi patches tons of packages and commands -- beside other `titlesec` and headers.

Load hebrew *after* titlesec but *before* defining the chapter format:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7.5in,
    paperheight=9.25in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]
    {geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[compact,pagestyles]{titlesec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}



        %changes page numbering to bottom outer
        \newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}                   {\thepage}}
        \pagestyle{mystyle}
        %

    %creates the chapter heading style
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries\rmfamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
    \vspace{1pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule
    \vspace{0pc}%
    \footnotesize}
    %
        %changes chapter heading distance from top
        \makeatletter
        \beforetitleunit=1ex\@plus.ex\@minus.2ex
        \makeatother
        \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{*-2.25}{*2}
        %

    %changes "Chapter" to "Story"
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\@chapapp{Story}
    \makeatother
    %
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{expex}




\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\lipsum[1-24]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love simple solutions!

Comment: Is this sort of order-of-loading issue a **feature** or a **bug** of LaTeX?